# Typescript dynamic types based on first argument

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of background tasks, and I fire them all using asyncTask. I would like TS to different typing information based on the value of taskName (the first arg). As different tasks have different set of args and thus types.

```
type NotifyEvent<T> = {
  taskName: T
}

type EventType = 'PUBLISH_CHANGELOG' | 'CREATE_INSIGHT' | 'CREATE_MESSAGE' | 'CREATE_STORY' | 'CREATE_ROADMAP_CATEGORY' | 'UPLOAD_LOGO' | 'CONNECT_DOMAIN' | 'JOIN_MEMBER'
type TrackEvent = {
  event: EventType
  changelogId?: string
  feedbackId?: string
  teamId: string
  userId?: string
  domainName?: string
  categoryId?: string
  roadmapItemId?: string
  messageId?: string
}

type IndexedTasks = {
  ['tasks.trackEvent']: TrackEvent
}

type NotifyExtended<TIndex extends IndexedTasks> = {
  [Property in keyof TIndex]: TIndex[Property]
}

type NotifyExtendedTwo = NotifyExtended<IndexedTasks>

export const asyncTask = async <T>({ taskName, ...taskArgs }: NotifyEvent<T>) => {
      switch (taskName) {
        case 'tasks.sendActivityToInternalSlack':
          await sendActivityToInternalSlack(taskArgs)
          break
        case 'tasks.postSignupTask':
          await postSignupTask(taskArgs)
          break
        case 'tasks.exportStoriesEmailTask':
          await exportStoriesEmailTask(taskArgs)
          break
```

Does anyone know a way where I can create a generic type that maps the taskArgs to dynamic types based on the input of taskName. Where the value to Type is mapped via IndexedTasks

Comment: Your example is quite verbose. You might get better quality answers quicker if you edit your question to only have a [_Minimal_ Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), only showing the strictly relevant parts of code!

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAyZXm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.